# Laravel - Eloquent select with count some related data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have following query:

```
Product::where('shop_id', $shop->id)->with('orderItems')->get()


Product: id | title 
OrderItem: id | product_id | sell_price | sold_quantity | sold_date
```

And i would like to count total income (what is sell_price * sold_quantity) and the same for last 30 days.

How to get all products for shop and calculate that data for every single one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DB::table('products as p')
->join('orderItems as oi','p.id','oi.product_id')
->where('p.shop_id', $shop->id)
->whereDate('created_at', '>=', Carbon::now()->subDays(30)->toDateTimeString())
->selectRaw('p.id,p.name, sum(oi.sell_price * oi.sold_quantity) as total,
  (select sum(sell_price * sold_quantity) from orderItems 
  where product_id = p.id) as grand_total')
->groupByRaw('p.id,p.name')
->get();
```

Comment: it works. But what if I would like to calculate to total value in one query not only latest 30 days?

Comment: Just comment the whereDate part and you will get overall sales amount of each product from the beginning to the end.

Comment: I mean get both values in one query.

Comment: have a look at the edited version of query.